# What type of tomatoes would be good for me to plant?

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes, variety-selection

I am completely new to gardening and growing plants so this is all new to me. I have an unused vegetable patch in my garden with plenty of space and as it now spring I am looking to plant in it.

I would like to grow tomates for cooking, specifically sauces. I live in London in the UK so not exactly a hot climate, and I doubt the soil quality in the patch is very good as it's been empty save for weeds for a few years.

They would also need to be relatively beginner friendly, I'm not against putting in work but I've never done this before.

I know that they come in different varieties and I'm not sure if there is any that fit these circumstamces or whether this is just a fool's errand. Thanks

Comment: https://www.rhs.org.uk/vegetables/tomatoes/grow-your-own  First Google hit on tomato to grow in London England

Comment: Plant some marigolds as well - they keep tomato hornworms at bay (as seen in personal trials perhaps 600m apart.) And they are quite beginner friendly.